# geckoview Android display or download pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, geckoview

Geckoview display or download pdf file

My apk car search pdf files on google, then you can click to download it with `BroadcastReceiver`, it work ed well with old version of `geckoview`.

The I decided to use a recent version of `geckoview` :

```
geckoview-arm64-v8a-85.0.20210208133944.aar
```

And with this version, I can't download the pdf file on the device but it displays automatically the pdf content on the `geckoview` tab.
How can I do to download it on the device without displaying it?

Thanks for you help

Christophe